# Re long list split

Tags: html, python-3.x, split, beautifulsoup

I have been struggling with this problem kinda while. Basicaly i need to split a loong HTML list(obviously i will not put it in here cos it is fricken massive). I tried the `str.split()` method but you can only put one parameter at the time. Soo i found the `re.split()` function. BUT! here is the thing if i try to split it, it blows this on me

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Plocha/FlaskWebsiteHere/Mrcasa_na_C.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = re.split(' / |</h3><p>|: 1\) ', something_paragraf[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 203, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

now i tried to resolve this but nothing :/. Please help!

SnailingGoat

Comment: what is an `html` list? since you've included `beautifulsoup` do you want to parse the `tags` in the `html` and split them? on the line your code fails you want to split `</h3><p>` tags, `regex`, this is a job for `beautifulsoup` not `regex`

Comment: The code is from my school homework site and i want to make my own thing to manage it. For example: `</div><div class="ukolRes"><h3>Španělský jazyk / splnit do 18. září (pondělí)</h3><p>vocabulario &#8211; &#8222;en la ciudad&#8220;</p>`. I want to parse it so i will have: Subject, When i need to finish it and The actuall homework.

Comment: Ok, with that example, this should work: `print(soup.find('h3').text)`, prints: `Španělský jazyk / splnit do 18. září (pondělí)`, but I can't tell if that is the same you ask for

Comment: The problem (i thing) is that it is not list but lists of list. For one subject there is one list. I have all the beautifull soup done i just need to parse it all in one. If you dont understand me (my english is bad) you can hit me on petr.gardas@gmail.com and talk about it. Thank You

Comment: can you post the html that you are trying to split on github.com?

Comment: https://github.com/SnailingGoat/HTML_code_for_downshitf . Here you go bro :D!

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe it wasn't necessary, I do also get `<div class="ukolRes"><h3>Matematika / splnit do 21. září (čtvrtek)</h3><ul>
<li>naučit se bezpodmínečně všechny tři mocninné vzorce</li>
<li>úkol byly příklady v sešitě na rozložení a složení vzorců</li>
</ul>
</div>`. The problem is you only want part of this text to display?

Comment: Ya exactly. And then i will put it on my site.

Comment: You want to only want the text? Change the last line to a `for` loop: `for s in something_paragraf:
    print(s.text)`. But that prints a few paragraphs. You only want the first 3 sentences?

Comment: No i dont care if it is a Raw html code or just a text i need to split it into multiple strings like this : ["Matematika", "splnit do 21. zari","naučit se bezpodmínečně všechny tři mocninné vzorce</li> <li>úkol byly příklady v sešitě na rozložení a složení vzorců "]. I have all the beautifulsoup things done i just need to proceed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
import re

something_paragraf = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"ukolRes"})

# convert 'bs4.element.ResultSet' to `str`
html = ''.join([s.text for s in something_paragraf]) 

# modify this regex split to suit your needs
# split string on punctuation
multiple_strings = re.split('(?<=[.,!/?]) +',html)

print(multiple_strings)
```

output:

```
['Matematika /', 'splnit do 21.', 'září (čtvrtek)\nnaučit se bezpodmínečně všechny tři mocninné vzorce\núkol byly příklady v sešitě na rozložení a složení vzorců\n\nAnglický jazyk /'
...
'lepidlo Kores,', 'tužky,', 'propiska či pero (modré)\n']
```

Comment: Actually i solved it.. But your answer is better :-). Thanks alot for all the support :-)

Comment: Thats great to hear, true - you probably learned more when you solved it yourself, good job!